# How do I change Visual Studio Code line number settings to start at zero?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is kind of for ease of use question since I'm writing assembly code and looking at machine code through Visual Studio Code as a text editor.
Is there anywhere in the settings of Visual Studio Code where I can change the starting line number to zero?

[image]

Comment: It seems that once proposed as one feature request (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79124), but unfortunately failed to be implemented for lack of upvotes.

Comment: feature request got re-hashed and got enough community support to get added to backlog. See the rehash here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144942